# flutter & firebase| I'm trying to show a snackBar for the users who doesn't have an account but it show in my terminal'[firebase_auth/user-not-found]'

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication

I created two authentications on the login page, one to the validation and one to check if the user had registered before (if they had an account). And my problem is when the user hasn't signed up before and they try to log in, they should see a SnackBar saying "Email or password is incorrect" but it doesn't work and it shows in terminal  "Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/user-not-found] There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted."

enum:

```
enum ViewState { Ideal, Busy }
enum AuthState { SignIn, SignUp }
```

AuthModel:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gray_green/enum/appState.dart';

import 'baseModel.dart';

BuildContext ctx;
// User currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

//UserCredential userCredential;

class AuthModel extends BaseModel {
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  void createNewUser(String email, String password) async {
    setViewState(ViewState.Busy);
    await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    setViewState(ViewState.Ideal);
  }

  void signIn(String email, String password) async {
    setViewState(ViewState.Busy);
    await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    setViewState(ViewState.Ideal);

  }

  void logOut() async {
    setViewState(ViewState.Busy);
    await firebaseAuth.signOut();
    setViewState(ViewState.Ideal);
  }
}
```

BaseModel:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gray_green/enum/appState.dart';

class BaseModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  ViewState _viewState;

  ViewState get viewState => _viewState;

  setViewState(ViewState viewState) {
    _viewState = viewState;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  AuthState _authState;

  AuthState get authState => _authState;

  setAuthState(AuthState authState) {
    _authState = authState;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // User _user;
  // set user(User user) {
  //   _user = user;
  //   notifyListeners();
  // }

  // get user => _user;

  // clear() {
  //   _user = null;
  //   notifyListeners();
  // }
}
```

AuthStateModelLogin:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:gray_green/enum/appState.dart';

import 'authModel.dart';
import 'baseModel.dart';

class authStateModelLogin extends BaseModel {
  switchAuthenticationState(AuthModel authModel) {
    authModel.authState == AuthState.SignIn
        ? authModel.setAuthState(AuthState.SignUp)
        : authModel.setAuthState(AuthState.SignIn);
  }

  switchAuthenticationMethod(
    AuthModel authModel,
    TextEditingController emailController,
    TextEditingController passwordController,
  ) {
    authModel.authState == AuthState.SignIn
        ? authModel.createNewUser(
            emailController.text,
            passwordController.text,
          )
        : authModel.signIn(
            emailController.text,
            passwordController.text,
          );
  }

  switchAuthenticationText(AuthModel authModel) {
    return authModel.authState == AuthState.SignIn ? "Sign Up" : "Sign in";
  }

  switchAuthenticationOption(AuthModel authModel) {
    return authModel.authState == AuthState.SignIn
        ? "Already registered?"
        : "Create account?";
  }
}
```

AuthPageLogin:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gray_green/enum/appState.dart';
import 'package:gray_green/model/authModel.dart';
import 'package:gray_green/model/authStateModelLogin.dart';

import 'ForgotPassword.dart';
import 'baseView.dart';

class AuthPageLogin extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController emailController;
  final TextEditingController passwordController;
  final AuthModel authModel;

  AuthPageLogin({
    @required this.emailController,
    @required this.passwordController,
    @required this.authModel,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    @override
        //User currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

        // FirebaseFirestore.instance
        //     .collection("users")
        //     .doc(currentUser.uid)
        //     .get()
        //     .then((DocumentSnapshot result) => Navigator.pushReplacement(
        //         context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage())))
        //     .catchError((err) => print(err));

        //  var snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('User deso not exists'));
        final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    return BaseView<authStateModelLogin>(
        builder: (context, authStateModelLogin, __) {
      return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Center(
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 350,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                        return 'Please enter a valid email address.';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Email"),
                    key: ValueKey('email'),
                    controller: emailController,
                  ),
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('passowrd'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 7) {
                        return 'Password must be at least 7 characters long.';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
                    obscureText: true,
                    controller: passwordController,
                  ),
                  authModel.viewState == ViewState.Busy
                      ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                      : SizedBox(
                          height: 25,
                        ),
                  ButtonTheme(
                    minWidth: 300.0,
                    height: 45.0,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        child: Text(
                          authStateModelLogin
                              .switchAuthenticationText(authModel),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        onPressed: () {
                          final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
                          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

                          if (authModel.authState == AuthState.SignIn ||
                              isValid) {
                            _formKey.currentState.save();
                            authStateModelLogin.switchAuthenticationMethod(
                                authModel, emailController, passwordController);
                          } else {
                            var snackBar = SnackBar(
                                content:
                                    Text('email or passwors is incoreect'));
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                .showSnackBar(snackBar);

                            //    if (emailController != AuthState.SignIn) {
                            //  } else {
                          }
                          ;
                        }),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                  if (authModel.authState != AuthState.SignIn)
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(
                          context,
                          ForgotPassword.id,
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Forgot Password?',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                    ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      authStateModelLogin.switchAuthenticationState(authModel);
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      authStateModelLogin.switchAuthenticationOption(authModel),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

**I have changed the authPageLogin into this so I handle the exception but still the same error**

```
if (authModel.authState == AuthState.SignIn ||
                          isValid) {
                        _formKey.currentState.save();
                        try {
                             authStateModelLogin.switchAuthenticationMethod(
                              authModel,
                              emailController,
                              passwordController);
                        } catch (error) {
                          switch (error.code) {
                            case "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
                            case "account-exists-with-different-credential":
                            case "email-already-in-use":
                              return errorMessage =
                                  "Email already used. Go to login page.";
                              break;
                            case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                            case "wrong-password":
                              return errorMessage =
                                  "Wrong email/password combination.";
                              break;
                            case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                            case "user-not-found":
                            case "firebase_auth/user-not-found":
                              return errorMessage =
                                  "No user found with this email.";
                              break;
                            case "ERROR_USER_DISABLED":
                            case "user-disabled":
                              return errorMessage = "User disabled.";
                              break;
                            case "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS":
                            case "operation-not-allowed":
                              return errorMessage =
                                  "Too many requests to log into this account.";
                              break;
                            case "ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED":
                            case "operation-not-allowed":
                              return errorMessage =
                                  "Server error, please try again later.";
                              break;
                            case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                            case "invalid-email":
                              return errorMessage =
                                  "Email address is invalid.";
                              break;
                            default:
                              return errorMessage =
                                  "Login failed. Please try again.";
                              break;
                          }
                        }
                        var snackBar =
                            SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage));

                        if (errorMessage != null) {
                          return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                              .showSnackBar(snackBar);
                        }
                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase will throw an exception when the user doesn't exist. So you need to catch that exception
in AuthModel.signIn wrap `signInWithEmailAndPassword` with a `try catch` block and catch the exception.

```
try{

    await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
} catch (e){
// show snackbar
}
```

it would be better to create an error handler class to handle exceptions

##### Some side notes for your coding

- Prefer final over var when you don't want to change the variable
- Try to write functions with low dependency (e.g. in switchAuthenticationMethod you are passing two text controllers. why just not passing their texts?)
- Be sensitive with naming your functions so others can read faster ( again e.g. switchAuthenticationMethod is not a switching method, it's doing sign in and sign up)

Comment: Thanks for your notes :), but still the same exception

Comment: @Lama Check it again

Comment: Now It shows " Failed assertion: line 222 pos 12: 'context != null': is not true." is it because I define BuildContext context in the authModel page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `await` keyword before the `switchAuthenticationMethod` method.

And you also need to add `Future` to the return types of your asynchronous methods.

- Update the `createNewUser` method to this:

```dart
Future<void> createNewUser(String email, String password) async {
 ...
}
```

- Update the `signIn` method to this:

```dart
Future<void> signIn(String email, String password) async {
  ...
}
```

- Update the `logOut` method to this:

```dart
Future<void> logOut() async {
  ...
}
```

- Update the `switchAuthenticationMethod` method to this:

```dart
Future<void> switchAuthenticationMethod(
    AuthModel authModel,
    TextEditingController emailController,
    TextEditingController passwordController,
  ) {
  ...  
}
```

- Update your login functionality to this:

```dart
if (authModel.authState == AuthState.SignIn || isValid) {
  _formKey.currentState.save();
  try {
    authStateModelLogin.switchAuthenticationMethod(
      authModel,
      emailController,
      passwordController);
  } catch (error) {
    switch (error.code) {
      ...                       
    }
  }
                        

  if (errorMessage != null) {
    var snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(errorMessage));
    return ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'You need to add the await keyword before the switchAuthenticationMethod method'?   but I tried it but still same issue 'Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/user-not-found] There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.'